# File upload test using Katalon when the 'browse' button isn't an input element

Tags: web-testing, katalon-studio

I want to test a file upload but as opposed to the [How to Handle File Uploads](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/handle-file-uploads/#) tutorial, the 'Browse' button in my case isn't an Input element.
I've attached a pic of the HTML script of the 'Browse' button: 
[html_script_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcqJ8.png)
and this is how it looks on the website:
[webpage_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxVpB.png)

How can I test a file upload in this case without dealing with the 'Open' explorer window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any input fields in your code, so you can't use `sendKeys()` method. There isn't any field to receive it. You should click on browse button and handle file upload dialog with an `AutoIT` script or `java.awt.Robot` class.